# docker not listing all containers when using -all

Tags: docker

```
os: linux xubuntu
docker version: 19.03.8
```

If I run two containers by:

```
docker container run hello-world
docker container run hello-world
```

and then do:

```
docker container ls -all
```

I should see two containers but I only see 1. 
If I remove that only container and do

```
docker container ls -all
```

I am able to see second container also.

Issue: as i understand the command 
docker container ls -all should show containers?

Comment: did you try  "docker ps -a "

Comment: you need two hyphens, not one.  `docker container ls --all` or `docker container ls -a`, not `docker-container ls -all`

Comment: @richyen you are correct. can you post this as answer so I can close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have a typo in your commands.  You need two hyphens, not one. `docker container ls --all` or `docker container ls -a`, not `docker-container ls -all`